# How to read multiple columns as labels using make_csv_dataset in tensorflow 2?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use the following code (that I found in Tensorflow tutorials [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv)) to read the data from a CSV file:

```
def get_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=5, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
      label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=True, 
      **kwargs)
  return dataset
```

It works fine when you have one column as the label column. However, in my CSV file I have multiple columns as labels (I have 1008 features and 2 columns as labels). I'm wondering how I can read my data using this make_csv_dataset.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow's `make_csv_dataset()` does not support data for multi-output models as of yet (It is experimental afterall). You can alternatively use pandas dataframe to read in the data and then use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` method to get your dataset. I would recommend memory mapping the csv data while creating the pandas dataframe as it would be faster this way